# Can the size and shape of penis be enhanced permanently?

Tags: medical-science, physiology, alternative-medicine, natural-remedies

A very good friend of mine went to the UK for his master's two years ago. After his breakup and several hookups (via online dating sites), he told me that he is very depressed, especially after one of the people he met explained to him that even though everything was okay, his penis didn't "flare" up during intercourse after he asked that person out of frustration.

According to him and his physician, he doesn't suffer from erectile dysfunction. Now, I don't know about the specifications of his penis (length and girth) and it is not of much concern to me, but he is considering all sorts of remedies, for example; jelqing, kegals, [hydro pumps](https://www.officialhydromaxpump.com/?a_aid=553cd768b4a37&data1=17116598)/[penis pumps](http://www.mensfaq.com/en/phallosan-forte-add-inches-penis-sleeping-feel-great.html), pills, etc. If none of them works after a long term usage, he said he would go for surgery.

But based on whatever I could find on the internet from several online forums, all of these techniques only yield short term/temporary results and they'd rather stick to their normal self or [improvise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_toy#Penile_toys) than using any of these dubious procedures. Here is a quote from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_penis_size#Anxiety):

> Products such as penis pumps, pills, and other dubious means of penis enlargement are some of the most marketed products in email spam. At present there is no consensus in the scientific community of any non-surgical technique that permanently increases either the thickness or length of the erect penis that already falls into the normal range (4.5" to 7").

But the same article (which was cited in the particular section of the Wikipedia article) links to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20101127025327/http://peinis.com/category/penis-exercise-programs/) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20101127024134/http://peinis.com/category/penis-enlargemenet-device/) article which has rather made me uncertain as to what to believe. Especially, the long term usage of any of such products. I am not sure about the surgery part, especially it being safe both in the short and long run, not to mention the cost of such surgeries. I'd be glad to know more about the same from some legitimate and unbiased studies/sources if any, so as to convince him to not waste his resources on such products and rather exercise regularly, consult a sexologist and psychologist (if needed).

Comment: I think it would help if you could focus your question a bit. It is unclear to me if the claim is about remedies for erectile dysfunction or about non-surgical penis enlargement.

Comment: I will say that the whole "penis enlargement" is a very widely held bit of woo that I am surprised hasn't been addressed here before. I agree, focus this on penis enlargement, and you have a winner question.

Comment: @tim - The OP did outline in the question that, "he doesn't suffer from erectile dysfunction." So I believe that it is purely permanent change to erect size that is the focus here.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins True, but then why even mention it? To me it seemed to indicate that there may be an issue that the friend considers to be a problem, but that isn't physical. I also read the "flare up" comment that way, and the exercise/sexologist suggestion (not that it will necessarily help with any problems in that area, but it will definitely not help with penis enlargement).

Comment: @tim I am just concerned about his mental and physical health for now because I suspect that he might be suffering from PTSD. As for the "flair" up part, what he/his partner meant actually is that the girth and/or length did not quite satisfy her during the intercourse and IMO, he might be attributing his past (failed/miserable) relationships to his penile length and/or girth. His partner did mention to him that his penis had no issue with the erection, which was also verified by his local physician. I'd apologise if I am being dense. I would clarify if needed.

Comment: @Kenshin - Yes, Lol. I am a virgin but my penile length is ~ 6.1'' and circumference is ~ 10.2 cm. :)

Comment: What confuses me the most is that most of these cited products come up with a money back guarantee. Maybe that is a marketing strategy and win over confidence of people, but I am not 100% sure of that. So, there's that.

Comment: "it's the size of your skills not your sex organ that matters"-http://time.com/2139/add-inches-no-really-men-can-make-it-longer/.

Comment: I'm concerned about this discussion being considered giving medical advice by non professionals, perhaps there is a better group for it.

Comment: Am I the only one that clicked on this thinking it would be a spam bot advertising miracle penis enlarging pills? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penile traction devices are noted to be effective in penile extension a.k.a lengthening.

> In conclusion, level 4 evidence (according to the Oxford Centre for Evidence-based Medicine) suggests that penile extenders are effective minimally invasive methods of penile lengthening, although further studies, preferably comparative, should be performed to gain more scientific evidence. Source: [Non-invasive methods of penile lengthening: fact or fiction?](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1464-410X.2010.09647.x/full)

FDA has also advised caution against use of penis enlargers and frequent/prolonged use of erection maintaining devices.

> The use of penis enlargers and erection maintaining rings may have harmful effects. They may aggravate existing medical conditions such a Pegronies disease, priapism, and urethral stricture. They may contuse or cause rupture of the subcutaneous blood vessels, which may produce hemorrhage and hematoma formation. Additionally, frequent use of erection maintaining rings may result in ecchymosis of the proximal portion of the penis and scrotum, and the lymphatic stasis of the penis. Prolonged use of the rings may cause gangrene of the penis. [Source: Import Alert 78-01](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cms_ia/importalert_226.html)